# ROW_NUMBER() OVER() returns the wrong order when used in a nested SQL DB2 query

Tags: db2, sql-order-by, rownum

I want the below query to delete the same rows which are returned by this select query:

```
 select emp_id, row_number(), over() as row_num from employee order by date_z desc
```

Delete query:

```
 delete from ( select emp_id, row_number(), over() as row_num from employee order by date_z desc ) where row_num < 100
```

But the row_num order completely gets reversed when the query is nested.
So, I end up deleting the last 100 rows instead of the first 100 rows.

A possible solution which works for me is:

```
 delete from ( select emp_id, row_number(), over(order by date_z desc) as row_num from employee order by date_z desc ) where row_num < 100
```

But most of the web links I went through propose that placing an order by clause in over is not going to ensure correct order. What is the right approach to achieve this?

Comment: FYI, the order becomes fine when the where clause is removed from the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
delete from
(select emp_id from employee order by date_z desc fetch first 100 rows only)
```

no real need for numbering rows.

EDIT: according to official documentation for 9.7 LUW [found here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-10-9) your approach with over(order by date_z desc) is also correct.

Comment: No, my use case is a bit different. I want to delete all rows after retaining the first 100 rows irrespective of the total number of rows. So if there are x rows, I want to delete (x-100) rows such that the deleted rows are the ones which have the earliest dates. This was my actual query:  delete from ( select emp_id, row_number(), over() as row_num from employee order by date_z desc ) where row_num > 100. I  want to now if putting the order clause within over() is conceptually the right approach as that gives me the correct result

Comment: @u009988 [Official documentation for 9.7 LUW](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-2-10-9) seems to state this is correct approach. You didn't specify version you're using, but at least for other LUW versions it should be the same